# Set custom BG Image for UITableViewAccessory?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to set a custom background image for a UITableViewCellAccessory. Is this possible? Basically, I want the functionality of an accessory, but with the look of a custom button.

Thanks!

Comment: Sam, there is not such thing as UITableViewCellAccessory. UITableViewCell has accessoryType (of UITableViewCellAccessoryType) and and accessoryView (of UIView). Just set a subclass of UIView to accessoryView or create subclass of UITableViewCell and layer it out by as you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, check the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1